# Retain strings in a column using a dictionary's value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to retain the string with the largest value based on a dictionary's key and value. Any suggestion to how to do it effectively?

```
fruit_dict = {
  "Apple": 10,
  "Watermelon": 20,
  "Cherry": 30
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "name": [
            "Apple, Watermelon",
            "Cherry, Watermelon",
            "Apple",
            "Cherry, Apple",
            "Cherry",
        ],
    }
)

   ID                name
0   1   Apple, Watermelon
1   2  Cherry, Watermelon
2   3               Apple
3   4       Cherry, Apple
4   5              Cherry
```

Expected output:

```
   ID        name
0   1  Watermelon
1   2      Cherry
2   3       Apple
3   4      Cherry
4   5      Cherry
```

Comment: Whats happnens if all values not matched per groups?

Comment: I was thinking to assign them into 0 in value but then the challenge is that if they don't get the matched key in the dict, would that run into a problem with the solution? One thing I can do is to use one of your answers in my other questions to filter it first but that's not ideal if we have a string has not match with the dict. @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way it to use `apply` with `max` and `fruit_dict.get` as key:

```
new_df = (df.assign(name=df['name'].str.split(', ')
            .apply(lambda l: max(l, key=fruit_dict.get)))
          )
```

or, if you expect some names to be missing from the dictionary:

```
new_df = (df.assign(name=df['name'].str.split(', ')
            .apply(lambda l: max(l, key=lambda x: fruit_dict.get(x, float('-inf'))))
          )
```

output:

```
   ID        name
0   1  Watermelon
1   2      Cherry
2   3       Apple
3   4      Cherry
4   5      Cherry
```

Comment: Hey @mozway, I really like the solution with name missing from the dict. I tested the edge case and it works great!

Comment: @codedancer you're welcome, if you have a large dataset, you might test a mix of this solution and that of @jezrael: `df['name'].apply(lambda x: max(x.split(', '), key=lambda x: fruit_dict.get(x, float('-inf'))))`, I expect this could be faster ;)

Comment: @jezrael I thought of it too late ;)

Comment: @mozway - tested edge state and aways returned first not matched value in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = (df.assign(name= df['name'].str.split(', '))
        .explode('name')
       .assign(new = lambda x: x['name'].map(fruit_dict))
        .sort_values(['ID', 'new'], ascending=[True, False])
        .drop_duplicates('ID')
       )
print (df)
   ID        name  new
0   1  Watermelon   20
1   2      Cherry   30
2   3       Apple   10
3   4      Cherry   30
4   5      Cherry   30
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: max(x.split(', '), key=fruit_dict.get))
print (df)
   ID                name         new
0   1   Apple, Watermelon  Watermelon
1   2  Cherry, Watermelon      Cherry
2   3               Apple       Apple
3   4       Cherry, Apple      Cherry
4   5              Cherry      Cherry
```

EDIT: If no match is returned first value:

```
fruit_dict = {
  "Apple": 10,
  "Watermelon": 20,
  "Cherry": 30
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "name": [
            "Apple, Watermelon",
            "Cherry, Watermelon",
            "Apple",
            "Cherry, Apple",
            "ooo, Cherry2, aaaa", <- changed data
        ],
    }
)
print (df)
```

---

```
df1 = (df.assign(name= df['name'].str.split(', '))
        .explode('name')
       .assign(new = lambda x: x['name'].map(fruit_dict))
        .sort_values(['ID', 'new'], ascending=[True, False])
        .drop_duplicates('ID')
       )
print (df1)
   ID        name   new
0   1  Watermelon  20.0
1   2      Cherry  30.0
2   3       Apple  10.0
3   4      Cherry  30.0
4   5         ooo   NaN
```

If need `NaN`s if no match:

```
df1['name'] = df1['name'].mask(df1.pop('new').isna())
print (df1)
   ID        name
0   1  Watermelon
1   2      Cherry
2   3       Apple
3   4      Cherry
4   5         NaN
```

---

```
df['new1'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: max(x.split(', '), key=lambda x: fruit_dict.get(x, float('-inf'))))

df['new2'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: max(x.split(', '), key=lambda x: fruit_dict.get(x, 0)))

df['new3'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: max(x.split(', '), key=lambda x: fruit_dict.get(x, 1000)))

print (df)
   ID                name        new1        new2        new3
0   1   Apple, Watermelon  Watermelon  Watermelon  Watermelon
1   2  Cherry, Watermelon      Cherry      Cherry      Cherry
2   3               Apple       Apple       Apple       Apple
3   4       Cherry, Apple      Cherry      Cherry      Cherry
4   5  ooo, Cherry2, aaaa         ooo         ooo         ooo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit_dict = {
    "Apple": 10,
    "Watermelon": 20,
    "Cherry": 30
}

df.assign(name=df.name.str.split(',')).name.map(lambda x:pd.Series(fruit_dict)[x].nlargest().index.values[0])

0    Watermelon
1        Cherry
2         Apple
3        Cherry
4        Cherry
Name: name, dtype: object
```